# dockerize a python/jinja2 program to generate a pdf document

Tags: python, pdf, docker, jinja2

I have written a python program that uses Jinja2 along with a Latex file (`template.tex`) to render the tex file dynamically, i.e. passing jinja variables to template.tex. The file is called jinja_engine.py. Here is what is executed:

```
# import functions
# import variables

if __name__ == '__main__':
    template = latex_jinja_env.get_template('template.tex')
    print (template.render(blocks = blocks, **options))
```

The program basically prints out the rendered file on the console.
I used docker to build an image of my program. Here is Dockerfile:

```
# base image
FROM python:3-onbuild

# run app
CMD ["python", "./jinja_engine.py"]
```

When I run the container, again, I get the rendered file printed on my console.

Next I would like to convert the rendered file to a pdf. In my application I could do that by first writing the rendered file to a file (example `out_file.tex`) and than using `subprocess` module to compile it, example `subprocess.call(['pdflatex', 'out_file.tex'], shell=False)`. My question is, how would I do that in a container? Shall I use a new container just to compile the output.tex to a pdf? What would you recommend? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create a shell script as main command of your container which, firstly, call your `jinja_engine.py` and redirect the standard output to a file inside the container.

`python jinja_engine.py > out.txt`

Then, you can call `pdflatex` from this script an generate PDF file.

Also, you should map a host directory to your container and write your output files to this directory. This way, you could use your container to generate `.tex` and `.pdf` files which will be availabe to you in the directory that you mapped to the container. This is done using option `-v host_directory:container_directory` in `docker run`.

Check this link for further reference to mount a host directory as a data volume in a container: https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just realized that just calling ´FROM python:3-onbuild´ in Dockerfile does not install ´pdflatex´ "command" in the container. Is there an image that allows me to do that?

Comment: Add a RUN instruction to your Dockerfile installing Latex.

`RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y texlive-latex-base`.

Validate the answer if it helps you :)

Comment: The problem is with latex. A basic install used in the container does not contain other packages that I use, example `lipsum.sty' package...so the pdf compilation fails..

Comment: So you'd have to install that packages or use another Docker image which contains Latex packages that you need. Currently, there are 519 repositories on DockerHub tagged with the word "Latex", so maybe you should take a look.